# How to get multiple errors validating XML file with Python libraries?

Tags: python, xml, validation, error-handling, lxml

I have some XML file i want to validate and i have to do it with Python. I've tryed to validate it with XSD with lxml. But i get only one error which occurs first but i need all errors and mismatches in XML file. Is there any method how i can manage to get list of all errors with lxml? Or are there any other Python solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to solve this problem was:

> ```
> try:
>     xmlschema.assertValid(xml_to_validate)
> except etree.DocumentInvalid, xml_errors:
>     pass
> print "List of errors:\r\n", xml_errors.error_log
> ```

May be there are better ways to solve this problem :)

Comment: What is the `xml_errors`, where does this come from?

Answer (score 4):

With `lxml`, you can iterate over `error_log` and print line number and error message for each error:

```py
def validate_with_lxml(xsd_tree, xml_tree):
    schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(xsd_tree)
    try:
        schema.assertValid(xml_tree)
    except lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid:
        print("Validation error(s):")
        for error in schema.error_log:
            print("  Line {}: {}".format(error.line, error.message))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [XMLSchema](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io) library you can resort to the `iter_errors` method: https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=iter_errors#xmlschema.XMLSchemaBase.iter_errors

here my code (Python 3):

```
def get_validation_errors(xml_file, xsd_uri='example.xsd'):
    xml_string = xml_file.read().decode('utf-8')
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    xsd_path = os.path.join(dir_path, xsd_uri)
    schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(xsd_path)
    validation_error_iterator = schema.iter_errors(xml_string)
    for idx, validation_error in enumerate(validation_error_iterator, start=1):
        print(f'[{idx}] path: {validation_error.path} | reason: {validation_error.reason}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can 
[read the Python docs on Error exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) to find out how to do a `try/except` design pattern, and in the `except` part you can store the mismatches (a list, or a list of pairs, for example), then recursively `try/except` again beginning at the point *after* the first error. Let me know if that isn't descriptive enough.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided doesn't work anymore due to several errors.
Before applying assertValid on xmlschema, you have to specify it as follows:

```
try:
   xmlschema_doc = lxml.etree.parse(filename)
   xmlschema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
   xmlschema.assertValid(elem_tree)
except lxml.etree.ParseError as e:
   raise lxml.etree.ParserError(str(e))
except lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid as e:
   if ignore_errors:
    raise lxml.etree.ValidationError("The Config tree is invalid with error 
       message:\n\n" + str(e))
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. How do the two bits of code fit together? What is elem_tree? Can someone please provide a complete example of working code?

Thank you - Rowan

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_validation_errors(xml_file, xsd_file):
    schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(xsd_file)
    validation_error_iterator = schema.iter_errors(xml_file)
    errors = list()
    for idx, validation_error in enumerate(validation_error_iterator, start=1):
        errors.append(validation_error.__str__())
        print(
            f'[{idx}] path: {validation_error.path} | reason: {validation_error.reason} | message: {validation_error.message}')
    return errors
```