# How to retrieve all validation differences when comparing XML file with XSD file

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have been trying to find the validation of XSD file with XML file. But unfortunately I am getting only the first difference while checking the files. I am using asssertValid() which only giving the first difference i.e., "Pane" from the file. It should find all the difference i.e., "Pane" and "Subpanel". I want all the validation difference in the log file. Could you please help me find all the differences.

Python Code

```
from lxml import etree
import traceback

def validate_xml_and_xsd_files(xml_path: str, xsd_path: str):
    result = False
    try:
       xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(xsd_path)
       xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
       xml_doc = etree.parse(xml_path)
       result = xmlschema.validate(xml_doc)
       xmlschema.assertValid(xml_doc)
    except Exception as ex:
       print("Exception raised-->", ''.join(traceback.format_exception(etype=type(ex), value=ex, tb=ex.__traceback__)))
    finally:
       return result


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     file_path = "C:\\Users\\"
     source_file_path = file_path + 'outputmetadata.xml'
     schema_file_path = file_path + 'XMLValidator.xsd'

     if validate_xml_and_xsd_files(source_file_path, schema_file_path):
         print('Validation Successful w.r.t XML and XSD files.')
     else:
         print('Validation Unsuccessful w.r.t XML and XSD files')
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataFeedDeliveryMetaData>
    <source>
            <setting name="countryCode" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>IND</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="startDateOfData" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>2012/12/31</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="endDateOfData" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>2013/03/24</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="currency" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>INR</value>
            </setting>
    </source>
    <delivery>
            <panels>
                    <panel>
                            <setting type="PersonName">Vikas</setting>
                            <setting type="Gender">Male</setting>
                    </panel>
                    <panel>
                            <setting type="PersonName">Akash</setting>
                            <setting type="Gender">Male</setting>
                    </panel>
                    <pane>
                            <setting type="PersonName">Divya</setting>
                            <setting type="Gender">Female</setting>
                    </pane>
                    <subpanel>
                            <setting type="PersonName">Manikanta</setting>
                            <setting type="Gender">Male</setting>
                    </subpanel>

            </panels>
            <setting name="JobType" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>FullTime</value>
            </setting>
    </delivery>
```

XSD file

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="dataFeedDeliveryMetaData">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="source">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="setting" maxOccurs="4" minOccurs="4">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                         <xs:enumeration value="countryCode"/>
                         <xs:enumeration value="startDateOfData"/>
                         <xs:enumeration value="endDateOfData"/>
                         <xs:enumeration value="currency"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>                      
              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="serializeAs" use="optional"/>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:unique name="settingNameAttribute">
        <xs:selector xpath="setting"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
      </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="delivery">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="panels">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="panel" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="setting" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                              <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                         <xs:enumeration value="PersonName"/>
                                         <xs:enumeration value="Gender"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                              </xs:attribute>
                            </xs:extension>
                          </xs:simpleContent>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                  <xs:unique name="panelTypeAttribute">
                    <xs:selector xpath="setting"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@type"/>
                  </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="setting" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                         <xs:enumeration value="JobType"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="serializeAs" use="optional"/>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Output

[image: Unable to get all difference pane and subpanel from xml file]

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/11581351/407651

Comment: Hi @mzjn but it is not finding th subpanel from the delivery tag. It is still finding the first difference only. Could you please help me fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import xmlschema


def get_validation_errors(xml_file, xsd_file):
    schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(xsd_file)
    validation_error_iterator = schema.iter_errors(xml_file)
    errors = list()
    for idx, validation_error in enumerate(validation_error_iterator, start=1):
        err = validation_error.__str__()
        errors.append(err)
        print(err)
    return errors

errors = get_validation_errors('stackover.xml', 'stackover.xsd')
```

## XML - stackover.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataFeedDeliveryMetaData>
    <source>
        <setting name="countryCode" serializeAs="String">
            <value>IND</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="startDateOfData" serializeAs="String">
            <value>2012/12/31</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="endDateOfData" serializeAs="String">
            <value>2013/03/24</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="currency" serializeAs="String">
            <value>INR</value>
        </setting>
    </source>
    <delivery>
        <panels>
            <panel>
                <setting type="PersonName">Vikas</setting>
                <setting type="Gender">Male</setting>
            </panel>
            <panel>
                <setting type="PersonName">Akash</setting>
                <setting type="Gender">Male</setting>
            </panel>
            <pane>
                <setting type="PersonName">Divya</setting>
                <setting type="Gender">Female</setting>
            </pane>
            <subpanel>
                <setting type="PersonName">Manikanta</setting>
                <setting type="Gender">Male</setting>
            </subpanel>

        </panels>
        <setting name="JobType" serializeAs="String">
            <value>FullTime</value>
        </setting>
    </delivery>
</dataFeedDeliveryMetaData>
```

## XSD - stackover.xsd

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="dataFeedDeliveryMetaData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="source">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="setting" maxOccurs="4" minOccurs="4">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:enumeration value="countryCode"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="startDateOfData"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="endDateOfData"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="currency"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="serializeAs" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="settingNameAttribute">
                        <xs:selector xpath="setting"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="delivery">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="panels">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="panel" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="setting" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                    <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
                                                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                                                <xs:enumeration value="PersonName"/>
                                                                                <xs:enumeration value="Gender"/>
                                                                            </xs:restriction>
                                                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                                                    </xs:attribute>
                                                                </xs:extension>
                                                            </xs:simpleContent>
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:unique name="panelTypeAttribute">
                                                <xs:selector xpath="setting"/>
                                                <xs:field xpath="@type"/>
                                            </xs:unique>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="setting" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:enumeration value="JobType"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="serializeAs" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```