# How to display all XML tag errors together?

Tags: python, xml

I am validating XML file. I need to display all tag errors like missing <, >, \ all together.
When I use following code, it is displaying only first error.

```
try:
    tree = ET.parse(filename)   
except Exception as e:
    excep = str(e)
print(excep)
```

I want to display all mismatches together.

```
Sample XML: (removed some <, > , \)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani<from>
<headingReminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I generated sample.xsd as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="note">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I was trying to execute Roger Dahl solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581351/how-to-get-multiple-errors-validating-xml-file-with-python-libraries)

```
def validate_with_lxml(xsd_tree, xml_tree):
    schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(xsd_tree)
    try:
        schema.assertValid(xml_tree)
    except lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid:
        print("Validation error(s):")
        for error in schema.error_log:
            print("  Line {}: {}".format(error.line, error.message))

validate_with_lxml("sample.xsd", "sample.xml")
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Ashok/xmlallerrors.py", line 85, in <module>
    validate_with_lxml("sample.xsd", "sample.xml")
  File "C:/Ashok/VLEX_BR_Tool/xmlallerrors.py", line 76, in validate_with_lxml
    schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(xsd_tree)
  File "src\lxml\xmlschema.pxi", line 53, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 41, in lxml.etree._documentOrRaise
TypeError: Invalid input object: str
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The XML parser will catch the first the first error, raise an exception and stop. You cant do it.

Comment: @balderman is there any other solution to print all errors together?

Comment: I am not aware of any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any mainstream XML parser that will continue after a wellformedness error such as those you describe.

However, IDE tools (I only checked Oxygen and IntelliJ) do seem to be able to flag multiple syntax errors in an XML document. I assume this means they are using their own hand-crafted XML parsers.

Comment: I am looking for a solution using python to display all errors together.

Comment: I know that. I'm telling you that I don't think you'll succeed.

Comment: @AshokAnumula: Often a well-formedness error is a kin to accidentally driving off a road:  A guardrail breach is obvious and useful to report, but any further problems encountered while the car falls off the cliff are hard-to-impossible to detect and report in a useful manner.

Comment: Can we achieve this by using python and xsd?

Comment: Firstly, please don't edit a question in such a way as to invalidate previous answers, it makes it very hard for anyone to work out what's going on. Secondly, adding a schema to an ill-formed file is irrelevant. The file has to be well-formed XML before it can be validated against a schema.